Next.js create base app/repo that can be extended
I'd like to create a Next.js project that can be used as a base theme/page which should can be extended/overwritten by pages and components, so the modified stuff wouldn't be changed on a repo update, but I don't know how to do this.
There is a Nuxt.js project called WooNuxt that does exactly what I want to do with Next.js.
This example shows to extend/replace the pages/components. The example contains the base pages and components in folder woonuxt_base and the app folder contains the custom stuff.
Any ideas how to do this with Next.js?
